# "SpeechToText" Using huggingface pretrained models but different results =>Wav2Vec2 vs other

Tags: android, nlp, pytorch, speech-to-text

I am new to NLP and I am using different pretrained model than Wav2Vec2.
I am now playing with createWav2Vec2 py. provided by Pytorch.
https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/blob/master/SpeechRecognition/create_wav2vec2.py

I load the pretrained model from hugging face , but during the sanity check , the transcribed text is wrong

Place i changed in code from

```
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")
```

To

```
model1 = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("patrickvonplaten/wav2vec2-base-timit-demo-colab")
```

Correct results
Result: I HAD THAT CURIOSITY BESIDE ME AT THIS MOMENT

But i got

```
Result: J <pad></s>DJ<pad>F</s>DJF<pad>JBJSN JKJCJ JFJO<pad>YLJCJ L<pad>HL<pad> F<pad>F</s> JC<pad>JHKJHLRFJ<pad>
```

Could somebody advise what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the alphabet variable in https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/blob/master/SpeechRecognition/create_wav2vec2.py. You should to replace it with here https://huggingface.co/patrickvonplaten/wav2vec2-base-timit-demo-colab/blob/main/vocab.json. You have to use only the keys of the dict as list.

For the `<pad>` you have to specify it in the load of the tokernizer/processor that you want it as `<pad>`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33666500)